# Wrong timestamp using $.now() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

jquery is getting me 13 digits timestamp instead of 10 digits timestamp when using this:

```
var timestamp = $.now();
alert(timestamp);
```

the result is **1382518196714** which is 13 digits instead of 10 digits.

How can I get the right timestamp using jquery?

Comment: new Date(1382518196714 ) returns Wed Oct 23 2013 10:49:56 GMT+0200  seems correct to me

Comment: This is correct behaviour.

Comment: My PHP tmestamp is cca 3 minutes forward than my browser timestamp. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript timestamp shows milliseconds instead of seconds since epoch.

Therefore:

```
1382518196714 milliseconds
```

and

```
d = new Date( 1382518196714 );
```

would give:

```
Wed Oct 23 2013 08:49:56 GMT+0000
```

Comment: How can I get the same value (10 digits like in php without using `+new Date / 1e3 | 0;` but with using `$.now()` ?

Comment: @JamesPriceless Why do you not want to use the division operator? `/`

Answer (score 3):

```
$.now() === (new Date).getTime()
```

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of **milliseconds** since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. You can use this method to help assign a date and time to another Date object.

In other words, `$.now()/1000` is what you're after.

[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: I dont want milliseconds. I just want the same format as PHP timestamp has

Comment: @JamesPriceless If you read the answer you will see that I convert milliseconds to seconds. It will result in the unix timestamp that you're after.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2snj/)**

use this javascript function:

```
function formatTimeOfDay(millisSinceEpoch) {
  var secondsSinceEpoch = (millisSinceEpoch / 1000) | 0;
  var secondsInDay = ((secondsSinceEpoch % 86400) + 86400) % 86400;
  var seconds = secondsInDay % 60;
  var minutes = ((secondsInDay / 60) | 0) % 60;
  var hours = (secondsInDay / 3600) | 0;
  return hours + (minutes < 10 ? ":0" : ":")
      + minutes + (seconds < 10 ? ":0" : ":")
      + seconds;
}

$(function () {
    alert(formatTimeOfDay($.now()));
});
```